# How to fetch elements of NSDictionary stored in an NSMutableArray in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have stored my contacts as a dictionary on an mutable array by this method:

```
 var addressBookReff: ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()
    var arrOfDictContacts:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    let people:NSArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookReff).takeRetainedValue()
    for person in people{
        if  let name:String = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
            let numbers:ABMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
            if let number:String = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers,0)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
                arrOfDictContacts.addObject(["\(name)":"\(number)"])
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, `arrOfDictContacts` is my mutable array which contains name and number as dictionary. Like this :

```
 arrOfDictContacts = ({ my = 12131;}, { doctor = 54445;}, { AL = 543212601;},  { customer = 121; } }
```

Now I have another array of names as

```
arrOfNames = [my, AL]
```

I want to get the respective numbers of the `arrOfNames` from `arrOfDictContacts`

**ExpectedOutput :**

```
  arrOfNumbers = [12131, 543212601]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Since your array contains dictionaries, the way to do it is to check each of the dictionaries against your array. Like following:

```
var arrOfNumbers : [String] = []
for dict in arrOfDictContacts {
    for name in arrOfNames {
        if let value = dict[name] as? String {
            arrOfNumbers.append(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: giving error in third line `name` that  `String is not convertible to Int`

Comment: Check out my edit. Since your dictionary values are String, the result array has to be `[String]`.

Comment: Check it now. The thing is that you have an array of dictionaries, but the edited version should work for you now.

Comment: No error now but am getting no output either. if I print `arrOfNumbers` , get [ ]. If I put break point inside two for loops, it is not stopping, it is not going inside the for loop I think

Comment: Maybe your `arrOfNames` is empty? Try declaring it as `let arrOfNames = ["my", "AL"]`. Worked for me.

Comment: no, it is not empty, If I print it, I can see the output.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong. The code I provided worked perfectly. Either your `arrOfDictContacts` or `arrOfNames` is empty or they names don't match the contact. Check your data and try again.

Comment: You were right. My `arrOfDictContacts` was empty as I declared duplicate unknowingly. Now it is working as a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, sorry this code is working with fetching all the numbers in `arrOfDictContacts` I want only the numbers with name of the array 'arrOfNames'.

Comment: No, it only fetches the matching values. I have checked it on a playground and it worked but it is obvious without even running the code.

Comment: can u come on chat? i dont know to start chat